# Is there something like a lorem ipsum generator?

Tags: shell, terminal, text

Is there something like a '[lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) generator'? I know it exists in Latex, and even in LibreOffice, but I'm looking for a terminal command. I would like to type something like `loremipsum 10 >> file1.txt` that would give me the first 10 paragraphs of lorem ipsum, each paragraph ended with one LF-character and 1 empty white line between each paragaph. And the output would be redirected to a file called file1.txt in the current directory.

Comment: [libtext-lorem-perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Lorem/bin/lorem)

Comment: Try this: http://code.google.com/p/pypsum/wiki/pypsum

Comment: http://www.lipsum.com has always been there when I needed it (yes, I know it isn't local, just offering another way).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the perl library `libtext-lorem-perl`. Here a short example, feel free to expand it to parse command line arguments, etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Text::Lorem;

my $text = Text::Lorem->new();
$paragraphs = $text->paragraphs(10);

print $paragraphs;
```

Comment: i got this error: Can't locate Text/Lorem.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./loremipsum.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./loremipsum.pl line 3.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't install the libtext-lorem-perl package. Will try again.

Comment: On Debian the `libtext-lorem-perl` package contains simple `lorem` command, so there is no urgent need for custom scripts.

Comment: Using it for a specific number of words fails for me: e.g. the output of `lorem -w 10` contains no spaces.

Answer (score 10):

found [this](http://www.bashoneliners.com/oneliners/oneliner/199/) at Bash One-Liners

```
 tr -dc a-z1-4 </dev/urandom | tr 1-2 ' \n' | awk 'length==0 || length>50' | tr 3-4 ' ' | sed 's/^ *//' | cat -s | sed 's/ / /g' |fmt
```

must be limited by another command or generates text infintely

Comment: fails on OS X 10.10 with `tr: Illegal byte sequence`

Comment: Random words are not the real thing though.

Comment: @ssc Try installing GNU `tr` (`brew install coreutils`) and replace `tr` with `gtr`.

Comment: tr on a Mac doesn't behave the same as on Linux. See this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141420/tr-complains-of-illegal-byte-sequence

Comment: If you want to awk on Mac you will need to install gawk `brew install gawk` just because of the type of linux that run's on mac.

Answer (score 8):

While not technically *Lorem Ipsum* or a local binary, there is an API on [Metaphorpsum](http://metaphorpsum.com/) which can output similar text but in English. I call it with `curl` like so:

- `curl http://metaphorpsum.com/sentences/3`
- `curl http://metaphorpsum.com/paragraphs/20`

Better still, you can define the API call as a function in your bash profile or scripts like this:

```bsh
loremipsum () {
if [ "${1}" = "" ] || [ "${2}" = "" ]; then
echo "Usage: loremipsum [paragraphs, sentences] [integer]"
else
curl -s http://metaphorpsum.com/"${1}"/"${2}" && printf "\n"
fi
}
```

You can then use it in a very similar way to your example:
`loremipsum paragraphs 10 >> file1.txt`

Answer (score 7):

[Fedora](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/lorem-ipsum-generator) and Arch Linux's [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/lorem-ipsum-generator/) have a [`lorem-ipsum-generator`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lorem-ipsum-generator/) package:

```
lorem-ipsum-generator -p 10 -l
```

will do exactly what you are asking for.

Another DIY alternative :

```
info bash -o -|shuf -n50|sed 's/  */ /g;s/^ //'|fmt -w 90
```

This outputs `bash` documentation into stdout, pipes it to `shuf` which randomly selects 50 lines, then `sed` removes multiple and leading spaces, and finally `fmt` formats it to lines approximately 90 characters long.

Of course this is just a starting point and you might need to refine the output, for which `sed`, `tr` and other string manipulators will help.

`shuf`, `fmt` and `tr` are parts of `coreutils` (which has a great chance of being already installed on your GNU/Linux distribution).

Comment: I fixed up your sed program a little bit and added a head to the pipe so you can select the number of lines you want: `info -a bash -o - | shuf -n50 | sed -n 's/  */ /g;s/^ //;/./p' | fmt -w 90 | head -8`

Answer (score 3):

## Generate random lorem ipsum text using Metaphorpsum API

#### Default to 3 sentences

```
lorem() { 
  curl -s http://metaphorpsum.com/sentences/${1-3} | pbcopy
  pbpaste | grep .
}
```

BOUNS: avoids curl progress, removes % from output, and adds to your clipboard for ease of pasting, while still displaying to stdout

## Example usage #1:

`lorem`

It's an undeniable fact, really; the starter is an outrigger. One cannot separate professors from moody gases. Few can name an unpraised oil that isn't a leery relative.

## Example usage #2:

`lorem 1`

The shrinelike swedish comes from a foremost syrup.

Answer (score 1):

The following command has been useful for me in many situations:

```
base64 /dev/urandom | awk '{print(0==NR%10)?"":$1}' | sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]/ /g' | head -50
```

This gives 50 lines where non-alphabetical characters obtained randomly from `base64 /dev/urandom` have been replaced by blank spaces: `sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]/ /g'`. Each line whose index is a multiple of 10 is replaced by the empty string (in order to simulate separation of paragraphs): `awk '{print(0==NR%10)?"":$1}'`.

You can add `| awk '{ print NR,$0 }'` at the end to get numbered lines (or any other that meets your needs). An executable bash-script `lipsum` that accepts the number of lines as argument could be useful.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
base64 /dev/urandom | awk '{print(0==NR%10)?"":$1}' | sed 's/[^[:alpha:]]/ /g' | head -$1 | awk '{ print NR,$0 }'
```

`lipsum 100 > output_file`

Comment: (1) Your awk command discards every tenth line.  It doesn’t matter for random text, but for less trivial applications you might want to use `awk '{print}0==NR%10{print""}'` to add a blank line after every tenth line. (2) Yes, `awk '{ print NR,$0 }'` will print line numbers, but note that there are other tools that are specifically designed to do that (like `nl` and `cat -n`).

Comment: Thanks @G-Man. (1) For less trivial applications you might consider `base64 /dev/urandom | sed '{0~10 s/^.*//;0~10!s/[^A-z]/ /g;50q0}'` but this one seems less clear to me. (2) Note that in this case, `nl` and `cat -n` do not give the same line-numbering.

Comment: Range `[^A-z]` can be problematic in some architectures, in such case use `base64 /dev/urandom | sed '{0~10 s/^.*//;0~10!s/[^A-Za-z]/ /g;50q0}'`

Answer (score 0):

Found two other python libs to be used

- https://github.com/camelware/camel-ipsum-python
- https://github.com/per9000/lorem

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple offline solution by means of one of the many lorem ipsum generators on the web. Store a moderate amount of text -- say 20 paragraphs -- in a file, and make the following script executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$HOME/lib/text/lorem_ipsum && cat $file
```

Answer (score 0):

Lorem Ipsum Generator Web site :
  - http://lorem-ipsum.perbang.dk/
(you can select nb of paragraph, etc)